# Attempting to delete multiple items from SP list using pnpjs V3 but getting error on ```createBatch()```

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, pnpjs

I'm following this documentation: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#add-multiple-items But I'm getting an error with sp.web.createBatch():

```
import { SPFI, spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/batching";
import { createBatch } from "@pnp/sp/batching";
let sp: SPFI;

export const DeleteItems = async (listName: string) => {
    const batch = sp.web.createBatch()
};
```

It's saying Property 'createBatch' does not exist on type 'IWeb & IInvokable'.

I'm using the latest v3 of sp/pnp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the issue using below

```
import { SPFI, spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/batching";
import "@pnp/sp/items/get-all";
import { createBatch } from "@pnp/sp/batching";
let sp: SPFI;

export const DeleteItems = async (listName: string) => {
    const list = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName);
    const items = await list.items.getAll();
    const [batchedListBehavior, execute] = createBatch(list);
    list.using(batchedListBehavior);
    items.forEach((i: IItem) => {
        list.items.getById(i["ID"]).delete();
    });
    await execute();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will help you to delete the large number of items from the list using batch concept:

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp/presets/all';

export default class MyWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {
  public async deleteItemsInBatches(): Promise<void> {
    const listName = 'YourListName';
    const batchSize = 5000;

    try {
      // Query the list to get the items you want to delete (using your own filters or criteria).
      const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.select('Id').top(batchSize).get();
      let totalItemsDeleted = 0;

      // Loop through the items in batches and delete them.
      while (items.length > 0) {
        const batch = sp.web.createBatch();
        
        // Add delete requests for each item in the batch.
        for (const item of items) {
          sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.getById(item.Id).inBatch(batch).delete();
          totalItemsDeleted++;
        }

        // Execute the batch operation.
        await batch.execute();

        // Query the next batch of items.
        items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.select('Id').top(batchSize).get();
      }

      console.log(`Total items deleted: ${totalItemsDeleted}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting items:', error);
    }
  }

  public render(): void {
    // Add your rendering logic here.
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution will help you to delete the large number of items from the list using batch concept